# How can you apply a plugin written as a Kotlin class to a Kotlin script plugin in Gradle

Tags: gradle, gradle-multi-project-build

I have a Gradle multi-module project.

If I:

1. Apply a Kotlin class plugin to another Kotlin class plugin:
   It's ok.
2. Apply a Kotlin script plugin to another Kotlin script (`.kts`) plugin:
   It's ok.
3. Apply a Kotlin script plugin to a Kotlin class plugin:
   It's ok.
4. Apply a Kotlin class plugin to Kotlin script (`.kts`) plugin: Error.

So when I apply a Kotlin class plugin to a Kotlin script (`.kts`) plugin, an error occurs saying that the plugin cannot be found.

Why doesn't it work in this case? I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for a script plugin to use a class plugin, the class plugin code must be on the classpath of the script plugin compilation ([docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#applying_external_plugins_in_precompiled_script_plugins)). Unfortunately the source files of the compilation of the same project are not added to that classpath.

Instead, this can be done by adding the class plugin to the `implementation` configuration in the buildscript for the script plugin.

If this is the same project where the class plugin code is located (in many cases `buildSrc`), this is not going to work as you'd end up with a circular dependency. So you are going to have to move your class plugin code to a new project.

You can do this by using an [included build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html). To do this:

1. Add a new directory (eg `classPlugins`) somewhere in your main project tree
2. Add a `settings.gradle.kts` file and a `build.gradle.kts` file to that directory
3. Write the `build.gradle.kts` file in the normal way for a plugin project, plus include group and version coordinates:

```
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        create("myPlugin") {
            id = "myClassPlugin"
            implementationClass = "mypackage.MyClass"
        }
    }
}

group = "t2k2ej"
version = "1.0.0"
```

4. Include the new build in your main project's settings.gradle.kts

```
includeBuild("classPlugins") // Put the relative path from the root to the new build
```

5. Add the new build to the classpath in your script plugin project (probably `buildSrc`):

```
dependencies {
    implementation("t2k2ej:classPlugins:1.0.0")
}
```

6. Finally, you can now apply the class plugin in your script plugin:

```
plugins {
    id("myClassPlugin")
}
```